# Is there a reward for beating levels with every weapon in Splatoon 2?

Tags: splatoon-2

Each level in Splatoon 2's campaign has a checklist for which weapons you've beaten it with. Finishing this checklist requires completing every level in Splatoon 2's single player at least 9 times.

**Is there any reward for completing each level in Splatoon 2 with every available weapon?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By beating every mission in Splatoon 2's Octo Canyon you unlock the hero replica of the weapon you beat all the missions with. The only exception to this is the Hero Brella which isn't released yet and Sheldon tells you that he is currently working on it, meaning this weapon should be released at a future date.

Comment: Are these weapons any better than the regular ones?

Comment: Nope all hero weapons are the same as the original weapon.